# How can I share data between two controllers, where the first controller is for a form, and the other is what will use the results from the first

Tags: angularjs

Basically, I've written two controllers.

The first controller is just in charge of taking an input from the search bar, and doing an $http request.  Here is the search function from the controller -

```
$scope.search = function() {
    $scope.searchString && 
      searchService.search($scope.searchString).then(function(results) {
        //what should I do here to share these results with the second controller?
      });
      $scope.searchString = null;
  }
```

The second controller needs to take these results and basically display them.  However, how can I at least get the results to console.log there?

So basically, there's a search, and there's a results.

When I submit the search form, the results need to show :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $scope.search = function() {
        $scope.searchString && 
          searchService.search($scope.searchString).then(function(results) {
            //what should I do here to share these results with the second controller?
           // if not working $emit then use $broadcast instead of $emit
           $scope.$emit('someEvent', results);


          });
          $scope.searchString = null;
      }


function otherController($scope) 
{
  $scope.$on('someEvent', function(event, args) {
     console.log(args);
  });

}
```

Comment: thanks.  whats the difference between $scope and $rootScope?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your controllers are not nested you can use $rootScope.emit()

```
  $scope.search = function() {
        $scope.searchString && 
          searchService.search($scope.searchString).then(function(results) {
            //what should I do here to share these results with the second controller?
           // if not working $emit then use $broadcast instead of $emit
           $rootScope.$emit('someEvent', results);


          });
          $scope.searchString = null;
      }


function displayController($scope) 
{
  $rootScope.$on('someEvent', function(event, args) {
     console.log(args);
  });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also create a service and inject it into both the controllers. Set form data from first controller. Access from second.

```
module.service('FormDataHolder', function(){
    var formData;

    this.setData = function(data) {
        formData = data;
    }
    this.getData = function(){
        return formData;
    }
})
```

Comment: how can I do the getData in my other controller after I handle the submit in the first controller?

Comment: basically i need to "listen" for data to be received.

Comment: Since angular services are singletons, once set, they will be available throughout app